# Persistent config with visitor pattern and static memory allocation

Tags: c++, serialization, embedded, visitor-pattern, static-allocation

I'm preparing a persistent config module for an embedded project. I want to use serialization implemented using the visitor pattern:

```
struct softwareInfo
{
    uint32_t version;
    std::array<uint8_t, 40> commitHash;
    uint32_t buildDate;

    template <class T>
    void pack(T& archive)
    {
        archive.process(version);
        archive.process(commitHash);
        archive.process(buildDate);
    }
};
```

When it comes to the storage module I'd like to register each structure like so:

```
PersistentConfig conf{};

conf.register(&softwareInfo, "swinfo"); 
conf.register(&foo, "foo");
```

and then perform either a write or read function that takes all registered objects and serializes or deserializes them either for write or read operations. Writing them all at the same time is more convenient as I cannot write to FLASH that had not been erased beforehand and a minimum erase size is a single page (2048B).

Since it's an embedded project I'd like to avoid dynamic allocations and I have troubles implementing the `PersistentConfig` class without it. I imagine it holding an array of pointers to some `persistentEntry`, to which I can register the structs:

```
struct persistentEntry
{
    EntryBase* object;
    std::string_view name;
    uint32_t size;
    uint32_t datacrc32;
};

std::array<persistentEntry, maxEntries> entries;
```

I thought of creating an EntryBase class and then a templated derived class which could hold the pointer to any type of registered objects:

```
class EntryBase
{
   public:
    virtual ~EntryBase() {}
    virtual bool pack(serializer::Packer& packer) = 0;
    virtual bool pack(serializer::Unpacker& unpacker) = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class Entry : public EntryBase
{
   public:
    explicit Entry(T* item) : item(item)
    {
    }

    bool pack(serializer::Packer& packer) override
    {
        return item->pack(packer);
    }

    bool pack(serializer::Unpacker& unpacker) override
    {
        return item->pack(unpacker);
    }

    T* const item;
};
```

but then I need to create Entry on heap during the register event:

```
template <class PackableObject>
bool registerEntry(PackableObject* obj, const std::string_view& name)
{
    entries.at(numberOfEntries).object = new Entry<PackableObject>(obj); //I'd like to avoid that 
    entries.at(numberOfEntries).name = name;
    entries.at(numberOfEntries).hashName = Checksum::crc32(name.data(), name.size());
    return ++numberOfEntries > maxEntries;
}
```

I also thought of holding only the pointer to the `pack` function, but since its also templated it won't work as well.

Is there a way to hold the registered structs pointers without the need to dynamically allocate the `Entry` objects? Or should I stick with this solution and just create a fixed memory pool that I can safely allocate from?

Comment: Did you saw `google::protobuf`?  There a virtual base of message (of `Entry` in your case) got methods that can copy underlying data without knowing what it is at call site - `MessageLite::New`, `MessageLite::CheckTypeAndMergeFrom`, etc. But underlying implementation there is indeed some pool maintained by library. Not at registy container site, but at "message" site. Depending on space and performance requirements,you actually could use protobuf to serialize your data

Comment: I roughly remember once solving the problem choosing a current  flash page, always containing the complete config, read it into a model, and save it to the next free one, marking it as the currently active one. Maybe that helps.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ it seems to be preferable with flash, because regardless of how much you write, it still writes by fixed blocks at once. Adding new data may cause an extra rewrite otherwise.

Comment: @swift as far I remember, we overcame of these low level media concerns as soon using a micro linux with a flash file system.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ if that's affordable, yeah. If it's something like PLD-based DSP computer,that might be a problem

Comment: @swift then I'd recommend going with my proposal, probably including to abstract the actual payload from the low level flash page management (active/inactive). I believe the latter was what I've implemented, and it was easy to configure just by initializing the correct hw-adresses of flash for a concrete device. But well, that's probably a very broad answer (question?) here.

Comment: _@klonyyy_ if how to save your config to the flash efficiently is your problem, then your question should focus on that problem, which doesn't have to do with the visitor pattern, or serialization formats directly.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm not sure if that's my problem - If I understood you correctly you're proposing switching two flash pages on every write so that I can incrementally add data. Is that right? Won't that be inefficient with small configs, and problematic when a config grows over the page size?

Comment: @klonyyy well, exploring the options you have for keeping your payload transparent, and versioned, after some experiments and measuring we decided it's still the best way to go.

Comment: @swift _@klonyyy_ ah, and yes of course we used protobuf for the payload formats.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm not saying it is a bad solution since I don't know the specifics of your application - it's just I think in my case (config read once at each startup and then saved only on explicit save command) would be better to just save all registered structs at once, especially when I might not have the FLASH memory needed to keep room for the incremental save "switch".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to hold the registered structs pointers without the need to dynamically allocate the Entry objects?

You still have the possibilities of [placement new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new), especially as all derived class has only one pointer as member.

```
struct persistentEntry
{
    aligned_storage_t<sizeof(Entry<void>), alignof(Entry<void>)> buffer;
    EntryBase* object;
    std::string_view name;
    uint32_t size;
    uint32_t datacrc32;

    template <class PackableObject>
    void init(PackableObject* obj, const std::string_view& name) {
        static_assert(sizeof(Entry<PackableObject>) <= sizeof(buffer));
        object = new (&buffer) Entry<PackableObject>(obj);
        this->name = name;
        datacrc32 = Checksum::crc32(name.data(), name.size());
    }
    
    void deinit() {
        object.~EntryBase();
    }

};
```

Another way is to mimic the vtable:

```
template <typename T>
bool packT(void* object, serializer::Packer& packer)
{
    reurn reinterpret_cast<T*>(object)->pack(packer);
}
template <typename T>
bool unpackT(void* object, serializer::Unpacker& unpacker)
{
    reurn reinterpret_cast<T*>(object)->pack(unpacker);
}

struct persistentEntry
{
    void* object = nullptr;
    bool (*pack)(void* object, serializer::Packer& packer) = nullptr;
    bool (*unpack)(void* object, serializer::Unpacker& unpacker) = nullptr;
    std::string_view name;
    uint32_t size;
    uint32_t datacrc32;

    template <class PackableObject>
    void init(PackableObject* obj, const std::string_view& name) {
        object = obj;
        pack = &packT<PackableObject>;
        unpack = &unpackT<PackableObject>;
        this->name = name;
        datacrc32 = Checksum::crc32(name.data(), name.size());
    }

    bool call_pack(serializer::Packer& packer) { return pack(obj, packer); }
    bool call_pack(serializer::Unpacker& unpacker) { return unpack(obj, unpacker); }
};
```